What are the units in a scipy mean peaks calculation?
I have a simple script that calculates the mean distance between troughs of a 100Hz PPG signal.
def avg_peak_width(ppg_signal):

  peaks, _ = signal.find_peaks(ppg_signal, prominence=400, distance=50)

  peak_widths = []

  # Iterate over each peak
  for peak in peaks:
    left_valley = measurements.minimum_position(ppg_signal[:peak])
    right_valley = measurements.minimum_position(ppg_signal[peak:]) + peak

  # Calculate the width of the peak
  peak_width = right_valley - left_valley

  # Append the width to the list
  peak_widths.append(peak_width)

  avg_width = sum(peak_widths) / len(peak_widths)

  return avg_width

Seems simple enough. But as you can see in the attached image, my peaks are at most 60-70  units apart. The entire sample if 60 seconds or 6000 points of data. But my result from this program are in the 1200s. If I print out the peaks themselves, the count of peaks matches the number of obvious peaks in this sample. So how can the mean width of the troughs be 1200? Does Scipy use some units that I am not aware of?


Turns out my code was an incorrect approach. This code works perfectly delivering the response in hundredths of a second.
def mean_trough_distance(ppg_signal):

  # Find troughs using scipy.signal.find_peaks with prominence set to negative for finding valleys.
  peaks, _ = find_peaks(ppg_signal, prominence=-400, distance = 50)

  # Calculate the distance between consecutive troughs
  trough_distances = np.diff(peaks)

  # Calculate the mean distance between troughs
  mean_distance = np.mean(trough_distances)

  return mean_distance

